# Calibrate Accelerometer?

Tags: ios, accelerometer

I know this is a very general and vague question but I am curious how to get this functionality into my app in the easiest way possible. I see many games out there, Doodle Jump is my #1 example where it allows you calibrate the accelerometer so if your sitting sideways the game will work good as new. How do they do this? I want the same functionality in my app but I am not sure what to do or where to go from here to get this functionality achieved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider "calibration" to be a constant reference to some root value or state.  When you want to reset your calibrations, simply reset the root value from which all other values are derived.  With the accelerometer, you have the luxury of knowing when a change is detected through a delegate callback, so all you need to do is write a method to "capture" the current state of the accelerometer.

In the [tutorial outlined here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/39833-tutorial-accelerometer-calibration-optimizations.html), such a method is outlined as:

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
     calibration = acceleration.y;
}
```

But, this isn't as "controlled" as we'd like it to be.  Instead, either break off your relation to `UIAccelerometer` as a delegate, or surround it with a `BOOL`ean property indicating whether or not you'll allow calibration to occur.  Something like this should work just fine:

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
     if (self.allowsCalibration)
         calibration = acceleration.y;
}
```

Comment: I have seen this before, but the thing is since he uses landscape, I am confused on how to apply this to my app that uses portrait. Also I am calibrating it from another view so I need some assistance on how to get it to calibrate from there. Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: When in portrait, it's like rotating a graph 90°.  Basically, just make every x point a y point. (ex. Float accelx is now Float accely).

Comment: Alright I gotcha so al the .x values are now .y values, and vice versa? Also what do you recommend for my calibration in a different view? How would I achieve that?

Comment: I haven't done much accelerometer work, so to calibrate in a different view, I'd assume the methods are still the same.  If you dont't mind me asking, what do you need this for anyhow?

Comment: Pretty much to let the user play while lying on their side or if their upside down or whatever.

Comment: Don't do that!  There is an orientation lock on the device for a reason!  But if you still want to keep going (I know how frustrating it is to rework your WHOLE code) then call a method to detect the change in orientation.  Usually -willrotatetointerfaceorientation

Comment: My app is only going to be in portrait but what if someone wants to play on their side, are they going to be SOL?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to "recalibrate" in that article.  And if your app is like doodle jump, then people have a general knowledge that the app is played sitting up in portrait mode.  It's all about user interaction in iOS: think if there are any situations where someone would NEED to play on their side.